# Pausing firebase connection when app is in background

Tags: angularjs, firebase, ionic-framework, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire

Is there anyway that I can pause connection from my ionic app to firebase when in background?

Answer (score 0):

You may try register a pause event and add firebase.app.App.database.goOffline() in the pause event.

And add firebase.app.App.database().goOnline() in the resume event